# show all users on a Catalyst Cisco switch

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, user-accounts

I am new to Cisco, I am having some difficulty:

I'd like to list all user accounts. `show users` only displays currently logged in users.

I have no problem changing the enable password, but I'd like to see all available users so I can change specific user passwords as well.

- How do I list all user accounts?
- How would I reset the password for a specific user?

Using 3750, 3560 switches and 55/10-20 ASAs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Q1. How do I list all user accounts?

From the enable prompt, run `show run | i username`...

```
CORE01.PUB.DAL01#sh run | i user
username operator password 7 <someHashedPassword>
CORE01.PUB.DAL01#
```

> Q2. How would I reset the password for a specific user?

Change the password from configuration mode

```
CORE01.PUB.DAL01#conf t
CORE01.PUB.DAL01(config)#username <someuser> password 0 <somepassword>
```

Syntax is slightly different for an ASA...

```
mpenning-fw(config)# user <someuser> password <somepassword>
```

Comment: You don't actually need to remove the user first (`no username <someuser>` you can just change the password with the `username` command.

Comment: That's not surprising, I just did not have a lab machine available to demonstrate, so I took the safest approach :-).  BTW, nice blog post about sysadmin team efficiency

Answer (score 3):

local users in Ciso IOS are listed in the running-config with the "username".

For your switches type "show run | b username" and look at the users listed there.

For the ASA it's a little bit easier, just type "show run username".

If the users are not local (radius, etc.) then you'll need to look on that server for the user list.

Answer (score 0):

To list all users:
"show running-config | include username"

If usernames are using secrets command to reset user secret:
"username %username% secret 0 %secret%"